# Android - can't get scroll view to scroll the list correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this pretty basic view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >         

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_label"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your question: "
    />     

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />         

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/question_text"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:hint="@string/question_comment_hint"  
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
            android:lines="4"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </EditText>

<Button  
            android:id="@+id/submit"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="@string/submit"  
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </Button>       



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please wait while the discussion loads..."
    />     

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>         

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I was hoping to do with it is to allow the user to scroll through the entire list of comments. As of now, when there are more comments then space on the screen, the screen does not scroll down.

Any idea what I should change to enable scrolling of the comments?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure it this is the problem, but you should never have a listview in a scrollview in Android.

Comment: @coder How come? You are right. It is kind of messing things up for me no matter what I try.  How would you organize this sort of page?

Comment: What exactly is the listview for? All of the comments?

Comment: @coder yeah the list is the list of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do away with the scrollview completely - based on what I THINK you're try to accomplish, since the listview will handle scrolling on its own. Like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >         

<TextView
android:id="@+id/question_label"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Your question: "
/>     

<TextView
android:id="@+id/question"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
/>         

    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/question_text"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:hint="@string/question_comment_hint"  
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
        android:lines="4"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </EditText>

<Button  
        android:id="@+id/submit"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="@string/submit"  
        android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </Button>       

<TextView
android:id="@+id/please_wait"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Please wait while the discussion loads..."
/>     

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >        
</ListView>
```

The difference now, is that the TextView with id "please_wait" will not scroll with the list. If you need it to scroll with the list, I would recommend using a dynamically built TableLayout in java for your list, then add that and your textview to a ScrollView. The TableLayout doesn't scroll on its own, and thats why its a better solution than using a ListView inside a ScrollView. If you want to do it this way, let me know and I will post some example code.

Comment: thanks - let me try this now. I knew I was getting into trouble with the nested scrollviews :)

Comment: oh yes that totally worked! Thank you. You definitely lived up to your screen name and then some! bravo.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to add a header above your comments in the ListView. As coder noted, you shouldn't put a ListView in a ScrollView. You should look at adding a header view directly to your ListView (see [`addHeaderView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)).

Answer (score 1):

basicly you can do like this:
get rid of scrollview and loading textview.
set a simple adaptor to your listview like this:

```
fList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstview);
fList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"Please wait while the discussion loads..."}));
```

Than get your comments and set to your listview.

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a ListView inside a ScrollView.
inflate a LinearLayout(vertical) instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your question: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/question_comment_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="4" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendFeedback"
        android:text="@string/submit" >
    </Button>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/please_wait"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please wait while the discussion loads..." />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/comments_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your code:

```
LinearLayout commentsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.comments_layout);
```

To populate the LinearLayout:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for(int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++){

        View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_list_item, commentsLayout, false);

        TextView comment = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.comment);

        comment.setText("Something");

        categoriesLayout.addView(childView, i);

    }
```

Something like that, hope this helps.